# Boost - ASIO vs. IOStreams TCP

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, iostream

I am new to Boost. I was looking for an easy cross-platform solution for sokcets/networking/TCP stuff and found Boost. A quick peek shows there seems to be *two* TCP related classes: One in **Iostreams** and one in **Asio**.
I am (pretty) sure if I dig into the respective documentations of both libraries I will be able to figure out the use of each one, but can someone explain in short what the difference is, or what each is used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a TCP stream in Boost.Iostreams?

ASIO is a complete full-featured networking library supporting asynchronous I/O using a generic callback API. The `ip::tcp::iostream` class (which is part of ASIO) is built on top of ASIO, hiding much of the complexity of creating and managing a socket manually and providing a standard iostream interface.

Answer (score 4):

I've used Boost IOStreams to easily create std::stream compatible stream objects. You can use them to create a TCP stream class, but you will be doing all the work to support TCP. IOStreams just provides a framework to create stream classes.

I've also used Boost Asio to create a stand-alone TCP server. Having used Windows sockets in the past to do the same sort of thing, I can tell you Asio makes writing TCP servers (and clients) really easy. I think Asio is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

As other have said, [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio) is probably what you want. It is an elegant and cross-platform wrapper for system specific networking stuff. It offer building block such as socket, IP address, timers, etc.

But it also offer a high level [iostream interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/iostream.html) for simple networking interactions. Here is a [simple example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/daytime_client.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: daytime_client <host>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    tcp::iostream s(argv[1], "daytime");
    if (!s)
    {
      std::cout << "Unable to connect: " << s.error().message() << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::getline(s, line);
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```